# Forcing SSL Protocol for Multisite Subdomain Child Sites + cPanel Configuration

Tags: multisite, ssl

I'm running a WP multisite using subdomains. I would like to force SSL protocol for all requests and am running into an issue for non-SSL requests on my child sites. I'm using the [WP Force SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/) plugin. I've done a bit of digging around and tried the following .htaccess directive, but it doesn't work (nor do anything):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For example:

- http://derpsite.tld = redirects to SSL Protocol
- https://derpsite.tld = works
- http://child1.derpsite.tld = breaks. Specifically, I get a `http://child1.derpsite.tld/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` cPanel error page
- https://child1.derpsite.tld = works

**EDIT 1**

I've reached out to both my host (dedicated server that has cPanel installed) and cPanel (the latter with whom I still have an open ticket).  cPanel has mentioned:

> Apache on cPanel is configured a bit different than other servers you may be used to. By default, Apache will accept any domain name being requested because it's set up as a wildcard. On cPanel servers, the virtualhosts are configured specifically for the domains you create. For example, when you created the cPanel account for defectslawyer.com, it set up a configuration that is specific to defectslawyer.com. Let's say I point the DNS for my domain thisisarealdomain.com to your server. When I make the request for thisisarealdomain.com, Apache checks it's configuration for that domain, doesn't find it, then returns the cPanel default page.
>
> It sounds like you have DNS configured correctly, I'm assuming a wildcard subdomain record pointing to your server, but Apache doesn't know what to do with what's being requested. At least on the non-SSL side of things. What should solve the problem is to add a wildcard subdomain in cPanel [ https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains ] so that the Apache vhost for *.derpsite.tld is added. Then, when *anything*.derpsite.tld is requested, Apache will be able to find that vhost and know what to load.
>
> The reason SSL version may be working is you likely installed the SSL as *.derpsite.tld which creates that SSL vhost.

Based on this input I have:

- Added a wildcard subdomain within cPanel (and have the subdomain document root point to the main site root)...which now kicks out a `500 internal server error` for both `http://child1.derpsite.tld` and `https://child1.derpsite.tld`)
- I'm currently reviewing how I have my SSL set up

**EDIT 2**

The `500 internal server error` above seems to have been the result of installing my SSL on a wildcard domain; please see my '[answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281376/47880)' below

Answer (score 2):

From the description of the error you get, it seems like you do not get at all to your account related software when trying to access the child on http. This sounds like a web server configuration error, so in your case you need to make sure that in your cpanel you enabled subdomains for http and not only https

Comment: Hi Mark. This makes sense. What cPanel settings (v 66.0.23) and / or config files would control this?

Comment: sorry been a long time since I worked with C-Panel, you should probably ask your support to verify the setting. I assume it is somewhere in the subdomain related settings

Comment: Hi Mark. No worries. I'm not seeing anything like that in cPanel (it seems to only have the option to 'add subdomains' (which creates the A record and directory...not much more than that). Do you happen to know what Apache configuration files would control this? I have an open ticket with our host and can get them to try things, but I'd like to try to help point them in the right direction.

Comment: it should be the file in which the virtual host for the domain is configured. it might be that there is only configuration for the https 443 port.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who commented on this, it definitely helped steer me towards the right direction and, finally, I believe that I know what happened, which was a combination of several factors. I realize that this may not be *'strictly* WP related', but for those using **cPanel**, the following should be of some assistance. I’ve compiled a few 'rule of thumb' items that, when all in place together, seem to have resolved the issue of forcing SSL protocols:

- `siteurl` and `home` fields in the options database table for each site (or in wp-admin ... `~/wp-admin/network/sites.php > Edit Site > Site Address (URL)` for each site) need to use `https://` in the URL
- If using a wildcard SSL *(which I imagine will be the case for most wanting to use SSL on a subdomain-driven multisite)* is [installed](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Install+an+SSL+Certificate+on+a+Domain) for the **root domain, not a wildcard domain**. I had my SSL installed on *`derpsite.tld` and removed/reinstalled it for `derpsite.tld`
- In DNS an ‘A’ wildcard record needs to point to the server IP, i.e. `*.derpsite.tld -> YOURSERVERIP`
- In cPanel, a [wildcard subdomain](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_enable_wildcard_subdomains/) (`*.derpsite.tld`) needs to be created and the subdomain directory should be the root directory (in most **cPanel** cases, this will be `/public_html` ...because, if running a multisite, you don’t actually want real directories to be created for 'child site' subdomains)
- Additional note: if you are doing domain mapping, you will likely have to '[park](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Park+a+Domain)' your external domain via WHM or cPanel to get it to run forced through SSL. Also, as of [4.5+ domain mapping is native](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping)). *Please note: at the time of writing I am using WP v.4.8.2 and cPanel v.66.0.23 ...sites running a WP version prior to 4.5 may require a different configuration*
- I'm not entirely sure if this is necessary, but I have the following directives in my root `.htacess` file:

`RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\-mapped\-external\-domain\.tld[NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-mapped-external-domain.tld/$1 [R,L]`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is not a WordPress related problem you had :0) and this forum is strictly WordPress related. I am glad you made it. @mark-kaplun updated you precisely `This sounds like a web server configuration error` which happens to be true.

Comment: Hi @prosti Yes, I agree. This is not strictly WP related (which I know now after further investigation), though I think it still is quite relevant to those who are trying to work with WP multisite.

Comment: @prosti server configuration required to run wordpress is on topic here, as long as it is related to wordpress is some way

Answer (score 0):

Because this is classed as 2 different domains, it will need to be done in 2 parts.  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^derpsite\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://derpsite.tld/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^child1\.derpsite\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://child1.derpsite.tld/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the reply on this. Unfortunately this isn't working for me either (neither locally - I'm using MAMP - ...nor on my production site (I'm also having my sysadmin look into this, but they are getting nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

You typically do not need to run plugins to force the SSL if you configured websever well.

You just need  `Settings -> General` and change both URLs to have `https://` rather than `http://`. Also purge the caching plugins is always the good idea. As I see the SSL certificates are in place and are working for you based on what you said.

The core of this plugin you mentioned is this:

```
// "The Core"
define('FORCE_SSL' , true);

if (defined('FORCE_SSL'))
  add_action('template_redirect', 'force_ssl');

function force_ssl(){

if ( FORCE_SSL && !is_ssl () )
 {
  wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
  exit();
 }
}
```

As you can see PHP or WordPress has been used to force the redirection. Instead these re-directions are better and smarter on webserver level. No PHP need to be used.

Comment: Hi @prosti. Thanks for the comment. I have actually set the `siteurl` and `home` fields (for all sites) set to contain https://. I've updated my initial thread with what I heard from cPanel (which I'm still working on)

Comment: Then your problem is not directly WordPress related @Ryan Dorn. You need to set the correct configuration on the web server since your certificates are OK.